# Adding parameters to XMLHttpRequests causes 405 Error

Tags: javascript, go, xmlhttprequest

I can successfully send an XMLHttpRequest without parameters using this code:

template file:

```
xhr.open('POST', '/mytemplate');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.onload = function() {
   if (xhr.status == 200) {
      alert('success');
   }
   else {
      alert('failed:' + xhr.status);
   }
}
xhr.send();
```

router:

```
r.HandleFunc("/mytemplate", MyHandler).Methods("POST")
```

But as soon as I try to add parameters I get a 405 error. I only change 2 lines, not sure what I am doing wrong:

template file:

```
xhr.open('POST', '/mytemplate?param1='+var1+'&param2='+var2+'&param3='+var3);
```

router:

```
r.HandleFunc("/mytemplate/{param1}/{param2}/{param2}", MyHandler).Methods("POST")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parameters in the open command are defined as URL query parameters (everything after the `?`).
But you added them as URL path parameters in the call to `r.HandleFunc`.

Try handling the base path of `/mytemplate` with `r.HandleFunc` and then parsing the query parameters in your `MyHandler` function with `r.URL.Query()`. That should return a map of the query parameters, which you should be able to reference by key (`param1`, `param2`...).

Stubbed out example below:

```
func myHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    //get the query vals
    values := r.URL.Query()

    //parse specific params
    param1 := values["param1"]

    //do other stuff
}

func main() {
    //define the handler
    http.HandleFunc("/myHandlerPath", myHandler)

    // do some other stuff?
    // ...

    // serve up the endpoint
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8081", nil))
}
```

Comment: if I did "r.URL.Query()" wouldn't that then apply to all my routers instead of just the particular one I want to handle the parameters of? Could you provide a code example? I am a little confused.

Comment: I'm suggesting you make that call inside your handler function for the particular route you're handling in order to read the query parameters from the request pointer in the handler function.

Comment: ahhh sorry totally misunderstood what you were saying thanks!

Comment: No problem! Examples always help :)

Answer (score 2):

You're handling a route that looks like this:

```
/mytemplate/some/variables/here
```

But you're sending the request to `/mytemplate` with query parameters, like this:

```
/mytemplate?param1=some&param2=variables&param3=here
```

Gorilla Mux won't match on these.  If you want to match query parameters, and not URL parameters, see the `.Queries` method in the Gorilla Mux [documentation](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux#Route.Queries).